# Getting the content of the first cell from a dynamically created element inside another cell

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am unable to retrieve the content of the first cell. I'm trying it like this:

```
console.log($(this).closest("tr").find('td:first').innerHTML);
//or...
console.log($('td:first', $(this).parents('tr')).text());
```

Code:

```
$('.editable').click(function () {
    var text = $(this).text();
    if (typeof $(this).find("textarea")[0]=="undefined")//checking if we have a textarea already
    {        
        $(this).text('');
        $('<textarea />').appendTo($(this)).val(text).select().blur(function () {

            var newText = $(this).val();
            $(this).parent().text(newText).find('textarea').remove();

            console.log($(this).closest("tr").find('td:first').innerHTML);
        });
    }
});
```

JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KjknL/

I think the problem has to do with the textarea being added dynamically. But I cannot move from it. If I use .prev() or .next(), it returns empty. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this: http://jsfiddle.net/KjknL/2/

the textarea doesn't exist anymore because you removed it just before trying to reach the first td from it.

```
console.log($(this).closest("tr").find('td:first').html());                
$(this).parent().text(newText).find('textarea').remove();
```

Comment: You're right. For some reason I assumed it would stay in memory until the blur function returned. Thanks. Will accept it in 8mins